# composite primary key as foreign key deleting one set delets all

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I have two tables one of them has composite primary key and the other has foreign keys to it. They both are set to cascade on delete. The problem is when I delete lets say a composite key set "name: John date: 02.02.2018" from the main table all the John rows are deleted from the table with the foreign keys, but there can be a set "name: John date: 04.04.2018" and also all rows where date is 02.02.2018 are also deleted how can I make it delete rows where only the set of foreign key is matched?

Update:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    session_date date NOT NULL,
    chat int(11) NOT NULL,
    message longtext NOT NULL,
    date time NOT NULL,
    receiver int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (date,receiver),
    KEY FK_messages_sessions (session_date,chat),
    KEY FK_messages_sessions_2 (chat,session_date),
    CONSTRAINT FK_messages_sessions 
        FOREIGN KEY (session_date) 
        REFERENCES sessions (session_date) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_messages_sessions_2 
       FOREIGN KEY (chat) 
       REFERENCES sessions (chat) 
       ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: It sounds like you didn't make the foreign key composite. Show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table with the foreign keys.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the answer. I tried to put  both of the colums in the other key index, but i guess it's not how its done?

Comment: @Barmar oh i just realised that i should just create one foreign key with 2 foreign colums not put every colums in each key.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined two foreign keys instead of a composite foreign key.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `session_date` date NOT NULL,
  `chat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `date` time NOT NULL,
  `receiver` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`receiver`),
  KEY `FK_messages_sessions` (`session_date`,`chat`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_messages_sessions` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`session_date`, `chat`) 
      REFERENCES `sessions` (`session_date`, `chat`) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

`(session_date,chat)` could also be `(chat,session_date)` depending on the order of these columns in the primary key defined in the referenced table.